# Unique factorization of free products of groups satisfying descending chain condition

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, free-groups, direct-product, free-product

I am self-studying group theory, and proving Exercise 11.61 of Rotman's *An Introduction to the Theory of Groups*, on free products:

> Let $A_1, \ldots, A_n, B_1, \ldots, B_m$ be indecomposable groups having both chain conditions. If $A_1 * \cdots * A_n \cong B_1 * \cdots * B_n$, then $n = m$ and there is a permutation $\sigma$ of $\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$ such that $B_{\sigma(i)} \cong A_i$ for all $i$.

(By "both chain conditions", it refers to the [ascending and descending chain conditions](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ascending_chain_condition) on normal subgroups.)

Edit: the below answer does not rely on indecomposability or ascending chain condition, just the descending chain condition.

Comment: No, it is indecomposable as a free product, **not** the direct product.

Comment: Ah, this is news to me, the book has only ever used it to mean in the sense of the direct product - how did you know, is there a counterexample disproving the statement for direct-product-indecomposable factors satisfying both chain conditions?

Comment: Just take $n=1$, $A=F_2$, free group of rank 2.

Comment: Didn't you ask this already? If you want to call attention to an old question, delete-and-repost is not the way to do it. [See here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3478/742).

Comment: A couple weeks ago I had asked and shortly removed a question with a different approach, because I realized the lemma I had in mind for the approach I had so far was not actually valid and would not actually work to imply the conclusion, so I had to rethink the question and the lemmas I wanted to prove.

Comment: I don't believe $F_2$ or $\mathbb{Z}$ satisfy the descending chain condition, since the group generated by $2^n$ always strictly contains the group generated by $2^{n+1}$.

Comment: If you don't ping (@ the person), the individual you are trying to reach may not be notified of your comment, unless they "own" the question/answer (as you do here). @MoisheKohan may not have seen your reply, and I only saw yours to me because I proactively re-visited the post. Note that you can only ping one person.

Comment: Oh, I missed these assumptions. I was assuming that Rotman wants you to prove the uniqueness part in [Grushko's decomposition theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grushko_theorem) as an exercise. This uniqueness part in Grushko's decomposition theorem will imply Exercise 11.61 but is much stronger.

Comment: @MoisheKohan I haven't gotten to that part yet but will keep it in mind for then - but as for this exercise, I do believe as a result that it means indecomposable in the sense of the direct product.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is this argument that does not even rely on $A_1, \ldots, A_n$ being indecomposable or satisfying ACC, just satisfying DCC:

By [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4634473/order-of-xy-in-various-quotients-of-the-free-product-g-1-g-2-where-x-in/), we can construct an infinite descending chain of normal subgroups of any free product with at least two nontrivial factors: if $N(g)$ denotes the normal subgroup generated by an element $g$, let $x$ and $y$ be nontrivial elements from two distinct factors of the free product, and consider:
$$N(xy) > N((xy)^2) > N((xy)^4) > \ldots > N((xy)^{2^n}) > \ldots$$

This proves that any free product with at least two nontrivial factors does not satisfy the DCC. As well, $F_1 \cong \mathbb{Z}$ does not satisfy the DCC, so no nontrivial free group satisfies the DCC. Therefore by Kurosh's theorem (which is in the next section after this exercise, but I'll take it!), the maximal subgroups of $A_1 * \cdots * A_n$ satisfying the DCC are precisely $A_1, \ldots, A_n$ and their conjugates. Partition the collection of these maximal such subgroups into equivalence classes for if they are conjugate, and pick one group from every equivalence class. We recover $A_1, \ldots, A_n$ up to isomorphism in some order.

Comment: That looks good! I thought it could probably done by using the Kurosh Theorem, but as you say that is the next section so I wonder what answer Rotman had in mind. (But there is another instance like that in the book - nobody seems to know how to do Exercise 2.8 that $S_n$ does not embed in $A_{n+1}$ using only what has been proved so far in the book.)

Comment: That's true! This also uses amalgams, by way of the linked question, which is also a later subject in Chapter 11. However, if there is an easier way to exhibit a descending chain of normal subgroups of any nontrivial free product, then that reliance can be removed.