# Order of $xy$ in various quotients of the free product $G_1 * G_2$, where $x \in G_1, y \in G_2$ are nontrivial

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, free-groups, quotient-group, free-product

Say we have two arbitrary nontrivial groups $G_1$ and $G_2$, and some arbitrary nontrivial elements $x \in G_1, y \in G_2$. Then it is known that the order of $xy$ in the free product $G_1 * G_2$ is infinite. However, quotienting $G_1 * G_2$ by the normal subgroup generated by $(xy)^n$ should create a group where the image of $xy$ has order dividing $n$.

The question I have is about the word "dividing" there: does this process always set the order of $xy$ to *exactly* $n$ (for any $n \in \mathbb{N}$)? Or is there some counterexample where, say, quotienting the free product by the normal subgroup generated by $(xy)^4$ makes $xy$ only have order $2$, or something along those lines?

(If this isn't true for $xy$ but it is true for some other word like $xyx^{-1}y^{-1}$ then I would be interested in knowing a word that it is true for.)

Comment: cf. [this Mathoverflow question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/356162/3959). In general, there is no restriction on the order of $xy$ if $x$ and $y$ are nontrivial of finite order.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin For arbitrary groups, yes; though I am wondering about $x, y$ from two distinct factors of a free product, that intuitively have "no relations" between them (or rather, the only relations come from the fact that the identity in $G_1$ and $G_2$ are the same element in $G_1 * G_2$) - and specifically whether quotienting by the normal subgroup generated by $(xy)^n$ guarantees the order of $xy$ is $n$, no matter what the groups $G_1$ and $G_2$ happen to be. For example, whether the normal subgroup generated by $(xy)^4$ doesn't actually secretly contain $(xy)^2$ somehow, and so on.

Comment: I understand your question, repeating in a comment is a waste. Taking $G_1$ and $G_2$ cyclic shows it doesn't happen there. For more general groups, when $x,y$ are torsion,  if $G$ is a group as described in the comment, you can amalgamate a copy of $G_1$ at the element $x$ and a copy of $G_2$ at the element $y$ to get a map from $G_1*G_2$ to this group which is the identity on $G_1$ and $G_2$ and maps $xy$ to an element of order exactly $n$, so that the normal closure of $\langle (xy)^n\rangle$ intersects $\langle xy\rangle$ at exactly $\langle(xy)^n\rangle$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Rewritten**

The intersection of the normal closure of $(xy)^n$ with $\langle xy\rangle$ will be exactly $\langle (xy)^n\rangle$; the order of the product in the named quotient will be exactly $n$.

To see this, let us first prove it when $G_1=\langle x\rangle$ and $G_2=\langle y\rangle$ are cyclic groups.

It is enough to produce *any* group $G$ with an element $r$ of order $|x|$, an element $s$ of order $|y|$, and where $rs$ is of order $n$. To see this, note that the universal property of $G_1*G_2$ will then yield a group homomorphism $\phi\colon G_1*G_2\to G$ with $\phi(x)=r$ and $\phi(y)=s$. The kernel of this map will contain $(xy)^n$, since $(rs)^n=1$; in particular, the kernel contains the normal closure of $\langle (xy)^n\rangle$. But since the image of $xy$ is of order exactly $n$, we have that $\ker(\phi)\cap\langle xy\rangle = \langle (xy)^n\rangle$, and hence the same holds for the normal closure of $(xy)^n$. That is, the normal closure of $(xy)^n$ in $G_1*G_2$ does not contain any element of the form $(xy)^k$ in which $n$ does not divide $k$.

If $x$ and $y$ have finite order, then we have the following:
For any positive integers $a,b,c\gt 1$, there exists a finite group $G$ and elements $r,s\in G$ such that the order of $r$ is $a$, the order of $s$ is $b$, and the order of $rs$ is $c$ (see e.g. [this Mathoverflow question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/356162/3959), and the answer which references Milne's course notes; or [this one](https://mathoverflow.net/q/76228/3959) which includes a proof). This gives the desired result.

If $x$ and $y$ are both of infinite order, then we can find an abelian group with the desired property: considering $\mathbb{Z}\times(\mathbb{Z}_n)$, and taking $r=(1,1)$ and $s=(-1,0)$.

If $x$ has infinite order and $y$ has order $b\gt 1$, then pick any $a\gt 1$; we know there is a group as above with elements $r$ and $s$ of orders $a$ and $b$, and $rs$ of order $n$. The universal property of $G_1*G_2$ gives a morphism mapping $x$ to $r$ and $y$ to $s$ in which $rs$ has order $n$, and so by the same argument as above we conclude that the normal closure of $(xy)^n$ contains $(xy)^k$ if and only if $n$ divides $k$.

This proves the case where $G_1$ and $G_2$ are cyclic.

Now assume that $G_1$ and $G_2$ are arbitrary, $x\in G_1$, and $y\in G_2$.

By the above, there exists a group $G$ and elements $r$ and $s$ in $G$ such that $|r|=|x|$, $|s|=|y|$, and $|rs|=n$ (for example, a suitable quotient of $\langle x\rangle * \langle y\rangle$). Now consider the amalgam obtained by identifying $x\in G_1$ with $r$ and $y\in G_2$ with $s$,
$$ (G_1*_{x=r} G)*_{y=s}G_2.$$
This group contains copies of $G_1$ and $G_2$, so we obtain a morphism $\phi$ from $G_1*G_2$ into it is one-to-one on $G_1$ and on $G_2$. The image of $xy$ under $\phi$ has order $n$, so again we see that the normal closure of $(xy)^n$ in $G_1*G_2$ contains $(xy)^k$ if and only if $n$ divides $k$.

So we conclude that in all cases, in $G_1*G_2/N$ where $N$ is the normal closure of $(xy)^n$, the element $xyN$ has order *exactly* $n$.

Comment: I haven't gotten to amalgams quite yet but I just did a bit of looking ahead to the normal form to convince myself that there are indeed imbeddings from the factors into the amalgam, and nothing else is "forced to be equal" by creating the amalgam. Assuming that, then this definitely works, thank you!